# TexStudio Setting

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

[image]

How do I remove the small white rectangles around the bracket? I have brackets set to autocomplete, and the only manual way of getting rid of them is to manually write the other bracket which I find to be a little annoying.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638472/213149

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `Ctrl-Shift-K` should get rid of them. This also works for similar situations, e.g. when you insert

```
\begin{enumerate}[keyvals]
\item 
\end{enumerate}
```

or so using the autocomplete pop-up for `\begin` where `keyvals` will be marked in a similar manner.