# How can I turnoff the boxes around characters in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

TeXstudio autocompletes parentheses and adds a square around the right parenthesis. It does the same for braces. I am fine with autocompletion, however these squares are distracting. I could not find an option to turn them off. Is it possible not to show the squares?

An image of the MWE is below showing the squares:

[image]

Note: This question is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450258/auto-parentheses-get-squared-in-texstudio). However, I want to turn off these squares and at the same time keep autocompletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for this!

First of all, you still need to turn parenthesis auto-completion off

[image]

---

In order to get back the auto-completion, you can make a macro for that

[image]

So that it works as expected

[image]

Comment: It really looks like a great workaround. Thank you. However, I followed your steps and the trigger does not work. Am I missing something? Is there another option that I have to set in Texstudio?

Comment: @Andre I have been using this for a long time so I forgot, how the default auto-completion works. I'm just used to this approach when you still need to type both brackes, but the cursor automatically, goes between of them.
Apparently, you want to leave only `\(`, `\[` and `\{` respectively for the trigger and then brackets will be closing itself.

Comment: There is an issue with Texstudio macros, but this link helped (https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/531). However, I've associated shortcuts to the (, [, { macros and they might work better than the triggers. Good not to have anymore the brackets around parentheses. Thank you

Comment: I had to write the macro again for another computer. Yes, the trigger should be `\(` instead of `\(\)` etc. Also, it is necessary to close and open texstudio to circumvent a bug, as described in the link in one of the comments here. Works fine. Thanks!